# How to convert AVAsset to NSData or save it to file manager

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, nsdata

I am trying to do that using `AVAsset` to record Audio file and then after first i store it on `NSFileManager` and after that by convert it to nsdata i Call API to store it.

I am successful to Create `AVAsset` recording file and play it using third party Class that is `SCPlayer`.

Now problem is that i don't know how to Use `AVAsset` file for save it in file manager and then after call API to sent it by converting it to `NSData`.

Is any way to convert `AVAsset` to `NSData`???

Please Help...

Comment: I posted a solution to this problem here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37611488/how-to-stream-a-video-with-avurlasset-and-save-to-disk-the-cached-data/37611489#37611489 For me it was not working only with AVAssetExportSession. I also added AVAssetResourceLoaderDelegate to make it work.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can do the following:

1. Use `AVAssetExportSession` to export your `AVAsset` object to a file
   path URL.
2. Convert it to `NSData` using its `dataWithContentsOfURL`
   method.

   ```
   NSURL *fileURL = nil;
   __block NSData *assetData = nil;

   // asset is you AVAsset object
   AVAssetExportSession *exportSession = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset:asset presetName:AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality];

   exportSession.outputURL = fileURL;
   // e.g .mov type 
   exportSession.outputFileType = AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie; 

   [exportSession exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^{
       assetData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:fileURL];
       NSLog(@"AVAsset saved to NSData.");
   }];
   ```
3. Don't forget to clean up the output file after doing whatever you need to do with it ;)

Comment: I think it is the way, since initializing NSData from library URL is not accepted (returns nil NSData)

Comment: Is there any way to export to an NSData variable in memory instead of directly saving to the file system?

Answer (score 7):

Swift 3

```
let manager = PHImageManager.default()    
manager.requestAVAsset(forVideo: asset, options: nil, resultHandler: { (avasset, audio, info) in
                if let avassetURL = avasset as? AVURLAsset {
                    guard let video = try? Data(contentsOf: avassetURL.url) else {
                        return
                    }
                    videoData = video
                }
            })
```

Comment: This does not request an export session. Is the NSData object actually playable after using this method?

Comment: The Data object is 0 bytes.

Answer (score 3):

You could have a look at [AVAssetExportSession](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAssetExportSession_Class/index.html)

```
AVAssetExportSession *exporter = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset:asset presetName:AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality];
exporter.outputURL = exportUrl;

[exporter exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^{
    // here your file will be saved into file system at specified exportUrl
}];
```

Comment: This worked for me, but I needed to add the following line:  `   exporter.outputFileType = AVFileTypeMPEG4;` because outputFileType cannot be NULL