# How to convert AVAsset to NSData using Swift?

Tags: swift, video, nsdata, mp4, avasset

I have variable

```
var videoFile: AVAsset!
```

and it contains (loaded with) MP4 video, already, so no need any URL to download or save to local disc.

I have need to convert that **videoFile to NSData** using **Swift**. How to do this conversion?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert AVAsset to NSData or save it to file manager](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28237412/how-to-convert-avasset-to-nsdata-or-save-it-to-file-manager)